# Update in Project default_time_zone not affecting timestamp

Tags: datetime, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

As part of setting GCP project level timezone to AEST, I have run the following command -

```
ALTER PROJECT `gcp-abc-def`
SET OPTIONS ( `region-us.default_time_zone` = 'Australia/Sydney')
```

Doing so, I see that current_datetime() is getting changed to AEST whereas timestamp remains UTC, as can be seen below.

Can someone help how this can be remedied? What other settings to be changed? [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`I see that current_datetime() is getting changed to AEST whereas timestamp remains UTC` this is because the `current_timestamp` function shows time in timestamp type. A [timestamp](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-types#timestamp_type) does not have a time zone; it represents the same instant in time globally. When querying for CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() it shows explicitly  in UTC by having zero time zone offset. When you convert a timestamp to some other type that isn't tied to a particular timezone, you can specify the timezone for the conversion.You can use `format_timestamp` to convert the timestamp into your zone specific time.

**Example:**

```
ALTER PROJECT `gcp-abc-def`
SET OPTIONS ( `region-us.default_time_zone` = 'Australia/Sydney');

select current_datetime() as cdt, current_timestamp() as cts,format_timestamp('%c',current_timestamp(),'Australia/Sydney') as cts2
```